# Can i input the parent version number at runtime in maven?

Tags: maven-2

I using maven to build my project and I am trying to input the parent version @ run time.

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0 </modelVersion>
  <name>Payroll Common</name>
  <parent>
        <groupId>com.adp</groupId>
        <artifactId>PayRoll</artifactId>
        <version>19.0-${build.version}</version>
  </parent>
  ..
</project>
```

mvn -Dbuild.version=101 install. It is throwing an error.

Reason: Cannot find parent: com.adp:PayRoll for project: null:payroll-common:jar:null for project null:payroll-common:jar:null

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Cannot find parent: com.adp:PayRoll for project: null:payroll-common:jar:null for project null:payroll-common:jar:null

Can you please help me, with wat I am doing wrong.

thanks
Nash

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.  Version numbers in the project or the parent must be fully-specified in the POM.

Answer (score 0):

you can either leave out the parent version or the project version. If maven sees only one of them, maven assumes they are the same.

b.t.w.: ${build.version} is not a valid replacement. You can use ${project.version} to get the version of your current project.

Comment: can you please elaborate. Even if a use project.version it gives me the same error.

Comment: can you give us some more pom information and directory structure information? maybe the com.adp.PayRoll project isn't in your repository.